# aggregate function warning by group clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, ms-access-2007

So ive been running to this problem constantly and maybe someone can give me a good explanation in how or why it wouldn't work. I'm trying to GROUP BY just one column CSHFutureTAs.Time and ive tried integrating the simple line

```
GROUP BY CSHFutureTAs.Time
```

however this gives me an error "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'TA' as part of an aggregate function", can anyone help me ??

Complete SQL (without the GROUP CLAUSE):

```
    SELECT CSHFutureTAs.TA
   , CSHFutureTAs.TIME AS CSHGeneralTAs_TIME
   , CSHFutureTAs.[CUT OFF         TIME]
   , CSHFutureTAs.SUNDAY AS CSHGeneralTAs_SUNDAY
   , CSHFutureTAs.MONDAY AS CSHGeneralTAs_MONDAY
   , CSHFutureTAs.TUESDAY AS CSHGeneralTAs_TUESDAY
   , CSHFutureTAs.WEDNESDAY AS CSHGeneralTAs_WEDNESDAY
   , CSHFutureTAs.THURSDAY AS CSHGeneralTAs_THURSDAY
   , CSHFutureTAs.FRIDAY AS CSHGeneralTAs_FRIDAY
   , CSHFutureTAs.SATURDAY AS CSHGeneralTAs_SATURDAY
   , FUT_Totals.TIME AS GeneralTotals_Time
   , FUT_Totals.SUNDAY AS GeneralTotals_SUNDAY
   , FUT_Totals.MONDAY AS GeneralTotals_MONDAY
   , FUT_Totals.TUESDAY AS GeneralTotals_TUESDAY
   , FUT_Totals.WEDNESDAY AS GeneralTotals_WEDNESDAY
   , FUT_Totals.THURSDAY AS GeneralTotals_THURSDAY
   , FUT_Totals.FRIDAY AS GeneralTotals_FRIDAY
   , FUT_Totals.SATURDAY AS GeneralTotals_SATURDAY
   , CSHFutureTAs.[EXCEPTION DAYS]
   , CSHFutureTAs.[EXCEPTION VALUE]
   , IIf([FUT_Totals] ! [Time] = "09:00 - 21:00"
      OR [FUT_Totals] ! [Time] = "10:00 - 22:00", 9, 1) AS SortKey
FROM
(
   CSHFutureTAs
   INNER JOIN FUT_Totals ON (CSHFutureTAs.[HG ID] = FUT_Totals.HG_ID)
      AND (CSHFutureTAs.TIME = FUT_Totals.TIME)
)
INNER JOIN Current_INFO ON (CSHFutureTAs.[HG ID] = Current_INFO.[HG ID])
   AND (CSHFutureTAs.[HEADER ID] = Current_INFO.[HEADER ID])
   AND (FUT_Totals.HG_ID = Current_INFO.[HG ID])
ORDER BY IIf([FUT_Totals] ! [Time] = "09:00 - 21:00"
      OR [FUT_Totals] ! [Time] = "10:00 - 22:00", 9, 1);
```

Comment: You must either GROUP BY or use an aggregate function (Sum, Count, First etc) on every field (column) in the select statement.

Comment: Please note that the homework tag is deprecated and should not be used. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: So there isn't any way that the rest of the columns could stay neutral, without the sum, count or first for example when i create a report and i can group by the time and it actually does work but its through a wizard in access.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions carefully before adding tags. The one of `[homework]` tells exactly why you should not use it.

Answer (score 1):

where exactly is your `GROUP BY CSHFutureTAs.Time` clause?

you need to group by one column, and any other column that is not part of the group must have an aggregation function on it like SUM or AVG for example.

Also I dont think you need that parentesys on your FROM. Why did you add that?

Comment: well i mentioned it above that i added it in before but i only show the sql statement without i was placing the line "GROUP BY ..." right before the order by. The parentheses are not required in the sql but it works.

Comment: so you are missing your aggregation functions

Comment: well yes i presume, my goal was to keep all other columns required as a regular expression while simply grouping to a single column without the need of first,last, avg ...etc.